# Swift: Why is UILabel not displaying data from dataSource into the collection view cells?

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview, datasource, uicollectionviewcell

My goal is to display the letters below in individual cells inside of a collection view. I am attempting to use a UILabel to display them on the screen. This is the code providing the data to be displayed:

```
let dataSource: [String] = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L"]
```

The UILabel was created in a separate file called MyCollectionViewCell.swift. The code below links the label on the storyboard to the source code. It then creates a function that takes each letter (given to it from the dataSource array in the CollectionViewController.swift file) and assigns it to the label so that it can be displayed on the screen.

```
class MyCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet var notesLabel: UILabel!
    
    func setup(with note: String){
        notesLabel?.text = note
    }
}
```

Lastly, the code below (written in CollectionViewController.swift) is supposed to go through each cell and pass in the value from the dataSource array into each cell from the collection view. The .setup() method assigns the string value to the UILabel:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: MyCollectionViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell 
    cell.setup(with: dataSource[indexPath.row]) 
    return cell
}
```

This was working when I followed this video:

[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TQOhsyWUhwg&t=527s](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WiZOT.jpg)

However, since the moment I deleted the original UILabel and created my own, I have not been able to get the UILabel to display the data from the dataSource array. The image below shows the output I am getting when I run the application:

[Look at the screenshot of the application here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WiZOT.jpg)

I have a feeling this may have something to do with a subview not being properly added to its parent view, or something along those lines. However, I am still a beginner with Swift so I'm not sure if that's what I am doing wrong.

I have tried:

- Changing this line to "item" instead of "row": `cell.setup(with: dataSource[indexPath.row])`
- Created an instance of MyCollectionViewCell inside of the "cellForItemAt" function and tried to assign the value of "cell" to the setup function
- Created the UILabel in CollectionView.swift instead of MyCollectionViewCell.swift
- Replaced "cell.setup(with: dataSource[indexPath.row])" with "cell.setup(with: "test")" to verify if the String "test" would display on each cell, but it did not.
- Took away the question mark in "notesLabel?.text = note" and it came back NIL

At this point I have tried a lot more things than that, but did not note them all as I was trying them. However, nothing has worked so far. I've been stuck with this problem for a few days now. If someone can help I will greatly appreciate it.

Comment: What is note in the setup function: func setup(with letter: String){
        notesLabel?.text = note
    }. - letter argument is not used?

Comment: Sorry. I meant to replaced "letter" for "note" when I submitted this question. Right now I am using the argument "note" and UILabel is still not displaying the data.

Answer (score 0):

**I solved this issue by creating a XIB file for the cell.**

However, the more I am learning about Xcode, I realized that the error could possibly be found in the XML file associated to the Storyboard (Interface Builder).

At the time of this error, I thought that the storyboard was possibly creating a file, but I did not know where to find it. I now know that the XML source code file is found here:

*Main.Storyboard -> Open As -> Source Code*

This is where the code for the connections made from the storyboard to the view controller are found.

Ex: *<outlet .property="name of object connected" />*

I possibly just needed to rename the property of the outlet to match my UILabel, and that would have also solved the problem. I hope this can help you if you're having the same issue. Comment or contact me if you have any questions.